# FinancialData - differents results in time

Tags: curated-data, finance, history

I use `FinancialData` to get historical stock prices (see code below). I update them each year to get new data. I found out that stock price for particular month (e.g. January 2005) changed. I downloaded data 2 years ago, 1 year ago and now. Why historical price changed? 
There were only 2 stock splits (2006 and 2011) so I think this should not have any affect.
Thanks for any ideas.

```
FinancialData["F:GAZ", {DateList[{2005, 01}], DateList[{2017, 02}], "Month"}];
```

Comment: Have you tried with "RawClose"? Read: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html  'For historical data, properties such as "High", "Low", "Close" are adjusted for stock splits, dividends and related changes.' and below.